# rebase conflicts on github while maintaining a linear commit history

Tags: git, github

I've been trying to  practise maintaining a linear commit history, and starting doing `rebase and merge` for my pull requests.

I basically have 3 branches, `master`, `develop` and `qa`. `develop` is branched off of master and `qa` from develop.

When a feature comes I branch off of `develop`(e.g. Feature-branch-1), commit, send a PR and `rebase and merge` to develop.

However, to deploy to qa, I send a PR from `develop` and `rebase and merge` to `qa`. The first time around it was ok. But, the second time I was doing this, I wasn't expecting merge conflicts.

I believe I am not understanding some basic principles for this to work. Is this behaviour expected? What is the reason?

Below are the screenshots of the steps:

1. Send feature PR to `develop`(branch later `rebase and merged` to develop):

[image]

2. `develop` successfully `rebase and merge`d to `qa` for the first time:

[image]

3. `Feature-branch-2` pr to `develop`(later `rebase and merge`d to develop):

[image]

4. PR from `deveop` to `qa` for the second time:

[image]

If I do a `merge commit` instead, this is how the `qa` branch then becomes:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any commits into `master` and `qa` that aren't coming from `develop`?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying , no, I strictly restrict to qa from develop... and I created the brand new above repository just to test it out... so I'm 100% sure

Comment: Oh, no.... I just read that you rebase `develop`. :-S Tip: **do not rebase long-lived branches**. Feature branches are fine to be rebased but long-lived branches (like `develop`, `master`, etc) are not ok to be rebased.... let me continue reading to see if this is something else on top of **that** problem.

Comment: Ok... yes... this is the problem..... and I answered something even with charts not that long ago... let me set it as a duplicate, hold it for a second.

Comment: Am I understanding it right that you rebased `develop` to `qa` but kept `develop` and tried to rebase it on top of `qa` again? In that case the error is simply that you already copied a bunch of commits to `qa` once and now when you try to copy them to `qa` again they are conflicting with themselves. You should never rebase-merge a branch `A` on top of another branch `B` if you intend to keep `A`.

Comment: If only `develop` goes into `qa` and only `qa` goes into `master`, what about exclusively doing fast-forward merges? Then you'd have a linear history without these issues.

Comment: @eftshift0 , I though `rebase and merge` simply copied the commits from A to B, is it not the case?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying , the options given by github have only to create a `merge commit` that destroy linear history, how do I configure ff merges there?

Comment: Merge it from the command line using [`git merge --ff-only branchWithNewCommits`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff-only) in the branch you want to merge to.

Comment: That would also mark the PR as merged. If you want to do it via GitHub, you can create an action that reacts on PR comments like `/merge` and performs the fast-forward merge or similar.

Comment: Nope.... `rebasing`  implies that **new commits** will be created on top of the target branch.... those commits are **not related** to the original commits that you are rebasing..... and hence, if you keep on using the _old_ branch, with the original commits, git will _not_ realize that those changes are already in.